# is possible use redirectView with jsp?

Tags: java, spring, redirect, modelandview

I need show a "message" after redirect with `modelAndView` but, as is well known, it not possible, then, I use redirectView, but i dont know how show a view.
In summary, i need transform this:

`ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("product/edit");`

in

`RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("product/edit");`

Comment: Sorry Your question is not clear to me. Please add more detail.

Comment: I need use `RedirectView` with a view in jsp

Comment: have a look at my answer that might help in this case.

Comment: You need the `RedirectAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

You can store message as `session` scope attribute and then redirect to jsp page where you can access it back using [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and [Expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String method1(...){
    ...
    session.setAttribute("message", "Hello, How are you?");
    return "redirect:product/edit";
}
```

*Note:* Here you can use `RedirectView` as well.

JSP:

```
${sessionScope.message}
```

Comment: `return "redirect:product/edit";` is not valid.
`product/edit` is a tiles-definitions

Comment: OK then use with `RedirectView` view but the concept is same. store the message in session attribute.

Comment: But if I use `RedirectView`, the constructor is only with a URL not with a view

Comment: Sorry I can't help you in that case. I have posted it from my working project. `redirect:product/edit` works. try some other options as well. What have you defined in configuration?

Comment: in servlet.xml i have define one resources `<import resource="config/tiles.xml"/>`, two bean ´<bean id="tilesConfigurer" ....>` and `<bean id="viewResolver"....>` and the ´tiles.xml´ have this structure:
´<value>/views/product/tiles.xml</value>´